# htaccess rules: least server load during brute force attack

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, brute-force

I want to limit access to wp-login.php. I am wondering which of the two methods has the least server load during a brute force attack.

```
<Files wp-login.php>
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from All
Allow from x.x.x.x
</Files>
```

or

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^openplease$ /wp-login.php?hfkan45dhfj76nshs [CO=accesss:666:mydomain.com,R,L] 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^hfkan45dhfj76nshs 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*accesss=666.*$ 
RewriteRule ^wp-login.php$ http://127.0.0.1/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . /index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

The first block of code limits access by allowing only one IP address, which means the IP address has to be checked with every POST request during the BFA.

The second one limits checking the conditions before redirecting the request to 127.0.0.1. The login page is renamed and when someone doesn't go via that page a cookie won't be set. If the login page doesn't have a url with hfkan45dhfj76nshs in it and there is no cookie available, access is denied.

Answer (score -1):

If you want avoid the risk of bruteforce attack, you could just change the adress of your login page using this plugin:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-login-url/

Comment: The address of the login page has already been changed in the code above, so I don't understand your answer. It's not answering the question either.